# How to detect https in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I am using CouchDB and I would like to transform some JSON (in a show) depending on whether the current request is over ssl or not. Is this possible?

The CouchDB request object doesn't seem to pass the raw url or the protocol.  I cannot rely on the port number as it may be a self signed cert on a non-standard port.

Comment: Can't you just append a query string to the show api? `_show/isHttps/your_doc_id?hasHttps=true` and then access it with `req.query.hasHttps` in the function itself. Would this work in your case?

Comment: The only way that this would be a secure option is if you're using the rewriter to serve your show functions, and appending the query parameter behind a reverse proxy. Otherwise, nothing is stopping the client from appending that query param on their own, regardless of protocol. Do you know how to create a setup like this? I could help with Apache if need be.